# Writing and Exporting Excel file Using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am Trying to fill my Excel sheet with the data i filtered through the methods i have made. For now i am getting a sheet but i only have only one row filled not the other it's not getting the data i provide it though my object

I am trying my sheet something similar to this sheet .
[image: desired sheet]

i am trying to write code in this part of code  :

```
public function export($Sets,$disp_filter)
{

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Offic excel Test Document");
$styleArray = array(
'font'  => array(
    'bold'  => true,
    'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
    'size'  => 10,
    'name'  => 'Verdana'


));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

  $excel_out =  array($this->outputSampleName($Sets));
  // var_dump($excel_out);
  // exit;


    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Sample Size and Margin of Error');
    $rowCount = 2;


    foreach ($excel_out as  $key=> $line)
    {
          $colCount = 'A';
          $i=0;
          // $line = array($Set['name']);
          // $CT = $Set['crossTabs']['base'];
          // $Moe = array($CT['sample']['moe']);

     foreach($line as  $col_value)
     {
        // var_dump($col_value);
        // exit;
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colCount.$rowCount, $col_value[$i])
         ->getStyle($colCount.$rowCount)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
      $colCount++;
     }
$rowCount++;
$i++;
    }
return $objPHPExcel;

}



protected function outputSampleName($Sets)
{

    foreach ($Sets as $Set)
    {
        $CT = $Set['crossTabs']['base'];
        $line = array(
            $Set['name'],

            $CT['sample']['moe'] . '%'

        );

        $excel_out []= $line;
    }

    return $excel_out;
}
```

when i see by var_dump($excel_out) 
i have this data structure :

[image]

[image: excel sheet downloaded]

**Please suggest me something how can i get those percentage values in my next row in optimized way. 
for now i can only loop through the sample[name] which are (enthusiasts, hunter, new shooters etc. )from that array. **
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because your array elements are arrays themselves, and you are trying to place these subarrays into cells.

Try setting each element of `$line` in separate cells:

```
foreach ($excel_out as $line)
{
    $colCount = 'A';

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $line[0])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $line[1])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $line[2])
            ->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $line[3])
            ->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $line[4]);
        $colCount++;

    $rowCount++;
}
```

Note that the first sub-array in `$excel_out` has only one element. You may want to store.
You could also use an inner loop to traverse through each `$line`.

**EDIT:**

After looking at the code in your answer.

Using inner loop:

```
oreach ($excel_out as $key=> $line)
{
      $colCount = 'A';
      $i = 0;
      foreach($line as $col_value)
      {
          // var_dump($col_value);
          // exit;
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colCount.$rowCount, $col_value[$i]);
         //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $col_value[1]);
         //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $col_value[2]);
         //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $col_value[3]);
         //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $col_value[4]);
         //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, $col_value[5]);
         $colCount++;
         $i++;
        //$rowCount++;
     }
     $rowCount++;
     // $colCount++;
}
```

Comment: I did not understand what you meant in your answer about looping through each heading...

Answer (score 0):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colCount.$rowCount, $line);
```

Seems like you're writing an array `$line` into a cell.  Should you do a loop from 0 to count($line) to put each element into a cell?

Comment: you mean one more loop in the body that foreach loop

Comment: Yes, similar to @kRiZ answer, but with a loop for elements of $line